gpu problems when booting parrot os
I try to install Parrot OS on an old windows PC that has GPU of Nvidia GeForce 710.
When I boot it in the default mode, It seems like it renders but then I get an error saying:
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM [DRM/000000001: kmsOutp] [HDMI head:0 enable: 1 max_ac_packet:15 ...

Then, I tried to boot while selecting disable nouveau and nvidia GPU and it boots ok.
Later, I tried to do:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver

But I got an error saying: "The system has a graphic card which is no longer handled by NVIDIA driver..."
I tried to download manually the driver and install it (had to stop and start lightdm for it) but I got errors.
Currently, I'm stuck with no nvidia and nouveau which makes the resolution huge.
When I try to use xrandr, it keeps failing. I tried to use cvt to add a new resolution but it won't add.
How can I continue here? I feel like I'm completely stuck.
Thank you!
SOLUTION:
So after a while the following solution did the thing:

Make sure to add nouveau to blacklist-nouveau.conf.
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off

sudo apt install nvidia-tesla-470-driver.



A Geforec GT710 is still supported by the legacy driver 470.xxx, available and automatically selected (or easily installable) in Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives. Knowing that ParrotOS is a specialized distro NOT intended as a typical desktop Linux it may not support your hardware. Use the aforementioned ones and you should have no problem.
